# How to pause loop while time is ticking

Tags: c#

I have made a timer where I can set time I want to wait and then do something.
So this is my short timer func:

```
private void Sleep(int interval, Action action)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer mytimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    mytimer.Interval = interval; //interval is in ms   
    mytimer.Start();
    mytimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        action();
        mytimer.Stop();
    };
}
```

And Im using this timer in loop:

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
   Sleep(5000, ()=> myAction());                                           
}
```

Without loop timer is great but in loop it wont work because loop wont stop and wait for those 5secs. It do all stuff imediately and starts timer again and again too fast.

So what Im trying to find out is how to make my loop wait until time runs out and myAction() is executed. Im working on forms application so all threadin sleeps wont work here. Also I tried all other timers but they used too much CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are better for adding all actions to a queue and then executing once the timer is elapsed.
Have only one time currently your code suggests you are creating a new timer each time the `Sleep` method is called.
Also the timer you are using runs on the main dispatcher of the current Window, 
may be you want to use a `DispatcherTimer` instead if you want to specify and run the timer on a different thread.

```
private Queue<Tuple<string,Action>> _queuedAction = new Queue<Tuple<string,Action>>();
```

then

```
foreach(var word in words){
 _queuedAction.Enqueue(new Tuple<string, Action>(word, ()=>{});
}
var timer= new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = interval;
timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
timer.Start();
```

then

```
private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e){
 if(!_queuedAction.Any()) return;
 var tuple = _queuedAction.Dequeue();
 //Execute your Action here.
 var word = tuple.Item1;
 var action = tuple.Item2;
 action();
}
```

here we are adding actions to a queue and every time the interval is elapsed the `OnTimeElapsed` method will get called then inside it we execute the action.

Else if you are looking for a synchronous solution we could simple have something like this

```
foreach(var word in words){
 DoSomethingWithWord(word);
 Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: I dont get it. I can run my timer in this queue and it will wait until it ends? And why "_timer.Start();" is outside loop? All the work is in loop so .start wouldnt be used. Sorry for my bad English, maybe I dont explain correctly what Im trying to do. For example I have 3 words so loop would go 3 times. So loop takes 1 Word and do some actions in other funcs like spliting and so on. Then waits some time and then takes another Word and do some actions. wait 5secs --> action(word1) ---> wait 5secs --> action(word2).. As I unsterdant correctly I can put all action()'s in queue but without "wait"

Comment: I have updated the answer; we start the timer and set an interval; each time the interval is elapsed we take an item out of the queue and execute an action on that item.

Comment: By the way, how I could remake these functions so I could use it everywhere I want to "wait"?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesn't stop because the timer doesn't actually execute any command which halts the current threads execution.

Though your example is a bit vague, i am assuming what you're looking for is`Task.Delay` which internally uses a timer. You can asynchronously wait it so the loop yields control back to the caller:

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    action();
}
```

Note this means you'll have to mark your method as `async Task`, or if its an event handler `async void`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it "seems" like it's happening again immediately is because your `foreach` loop is actually happening without any delays -- at the speed your processor can loop -- and calling `Sleep` many, many times right away, thus queuing up all those timers which are each waiting your 5000 milliseconds, then all firing your action after that.

You could do this instead of your `foreach` loop and get rid of all the other code (i.e. the `Sleep` method):

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(x => this.Invoke(myAction)), null, 5000, 5000);
    });
```

Note a few things here:

- The UI thread is not blocked by the timer because it's being run on a separate thread, whereas your code would block the UI as it was looping.
- The timer class being used is a `System.Threading.Timer`, not a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) for a good explanation of the .NET timers)
- If you want to perform any operations on the UI thread from within the timer (i.e. within your `myAction` delegate) you must do so using `this.Invoke(myAction)` which is one of the important rules of multithreaded operations involving the UI thread.

Comment: Its complicated with multithreads for me as my code is very dependant on gui. Anyway, thanks for help, Ill try to experiment more with your code.